# How Do You Change The Background Color of All Buttons?

Tags: java, android, xml

In the XML files on Android Studio, I created a theme for my app and wondering how to change all the button background colors in my theme in API 10? Here's what I got so far:

```
//Colors for certain widgets
  <color name="textView_Color">#505050</color>
  <color name="Button_Color">#878787</color>
  <color name="Background_Color">#ffffff</color>

//Where I assign the colors
<style name="mainTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/textView_Color</item>
  <item name="android:         ">@color/Button_Color</item>
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/Background_Color</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the appcompat support library and use the [Theme support it gives you](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

Comment: I am a little new to this and still haven't memorized where everything is and all the code. How do I use the appcompat support library again? Sorry again...

Comment: Check the link I posted, refer to the section "Setup"

Comment: @AJ213 first download and install the library files to your Android SDK installation

Comment: @RyanFung Yah... I forgot that and now my gradle is infinitely loading... Thanks.